# Invoke Open Resource Dialog in eclipse

Tags: eclipse

In my eclipse plugin, when i perform an action on the tree a resource in the workspace has to be opened exactly the same way as it happens when we press a Ctrl+ Shift + R(as the resource name would be displayed on the Tree). I invoked the OpenResourceDialog programatically through an action.

When i export the plugin and import it into eclipse, the plugin is not installed correctly. When i remove the dependency org.eclipse.ui.ide from the plugin.xml, the plugin is installed correctly. Arent we allowed to use the org.eclipse.ui.ide in our custom plugins?. If so, is it incorrect to invoke the OpenResourceDialog inside the org.eclipse.ui.ide plugin.

Comment: You can certainly use org.eclipse.ui.ide. What error do you get when you install it with the dependency on ide?

Comment: I extract my plugin, put it inside the plugins folder of eclipse and restart eclipse to see the changes. The plugin is just not visible in the Perspective menu and I get no errors in the Eclipse workspace. Should i check any specific log for the error?

Comment: You want to put your plugin in the dropins/plugins folder, not the plugins folder. It won't do anything with it in the plugins folder. See the p2 documentation for more information (older versions of Eclipse used to use the plugins for this).

Comment: Yes I am using Helios Service Release 2 version , the dropins folder is empty and all the plugins are inside the plugins folder.

Comment: I think i found out the problem as to why it was not showing. I was adding org.eclipse.ui.ide jar with version 3.7.100 in the eclipse i was developing the plugin, but this jar is not there in the eclipse where i import the plugin. I removed the bundle-version from the MANIFEST file and imported it again. It is visible now. Will check if the OpenResourceDialog fits to my requirement :).